# Allocate C++ object across MSVCRT versions

Tags: c++, static-linking, msvcrt

I have VS2010 and i need to build application.
Also i have .dll with .lib and .h built with VS2005.
This library depend on log4cxx.dll (i built 2010 and downloaded 2005 binary).
When i call library interface method which return reference to built object it throw AV exception. I can't build my app with another version and i've already tried change to Multithreaded Debug my app type.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that object you are getting has another memory layout.
If you are passing c++ object across runtime boundaries you should be sure that recieving object has the same layout. For example if VS2005 compiler have reordered it fields for optimization and VS2010 done it other way. Or one of classes you used (eg std::string) changed between versions. Read how objects are returned from COM methods.

There is also problem with object allocation in one runtime and deallocation in another...

As a solution you can try installing VS2005, but there is no guarantees that you end up same

Comment: Situation is more interest: i have VS2005 dll, which depend on log4cxx VS2008 and i'm trying to link library from VS2010. and it crash in a such point: i'm creating vector in app and pass it to library and it crash on release

Comment: @deeptowncitizen It's really bad situation :) But as I said, passing objects, that are not specially designed for that (std::vector is not) between runtimes is dangerous. Even using one version of VS you may get errors, for example if one side defines SECURE_SCL and another is not. The objects would be different.

Comment: I think here is something another: i create vector on stack in my app and pass it by reference to the function (which is const method in library). so here is shouldn't be some memory problems. Am i right? library just call push_back of my memory vector

Comment: No, there are plenty problems.
Don't think that it is your vector, it is your *memory*.
You are passing only pointer(reference is a syntax sugar for ptr) to module, it is interpreted module's vector. If layout changes module's vector's fields would not match originals. Another problem, if layout is ok, if module calls push_back, and capacity max is reached it firstly deallocates memory(in another runtime!!) and than allocates new, in module's runtime. Baaaad. Clear? Or I need to refine some places?

Comment: I've tried reserve enough capacity in vector, but DLL master must be clear it and then add items =) soooo bad (